# SSL exception during consuming web service in weblogic 12c with CXF generated client

Tags: java, ssl, cxf, weblogic12c, webservices-client

I've got a CXF 2.7.18-enabled SOAP WebService client in Weblogic 12.1.3.0.3.
There is an SSL check during WebService Proxy Client creation and it passes. 
But during an actual method call I get an SSL exception (below).

If I add properties with Weblogic trustStore path explicitly/programmatically or into cxf.xml trustManager tag, everything works, so it looks like CXF service does not use some Weblogic's API with filled certificates during the actual call.

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\<...>\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=DemoTrustKeyStorePassPhrase
@Rem -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\<...>\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=DemoTrustKeyStorePassPhrase
```

This is my cxf.xml file.
When I uncomment custom trust manager pointing at my weblogic DemoTrust.jks messages get sent, otherwise I get an exception.

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
        <http-conf:client Connection="Keep-Alive"
                          ConnectionTimeout="300000"
                          ReceiveTimeout="10800000"
                          CacheControl="no-cache"/>
        <http-conf:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true" >
            <!--<sec:trustManagers >
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="DemoTrustKeyStorePassPhrase"
                              file="C:\...\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks"/>
            </sec:trustManagers>-->
        </http-conf:tlsClientParameters>
    </http-conf:conduit>
```

I've also tried with `useHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory="true"` but to no avail.

I've also tried to play with Weblogic server SSL options.

Also I've looked at things like this, I was unable to figure out how to use it in Weblogic:
[How to set up Apache CXF client to use WebSphere truststore? (Receiving "No trusted certificate found" exception.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275063/how-to-set-up-apache-cxf-client-to-use-websphere-truststore-receiving-no-trus)

This is my weblogic-application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application
                xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>

    <!--<prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.wsdl.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.cxf.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>-->

</weblogic-application>
```

And this is an exception itself:

```
Nov 18, 2015 3:37:24 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for <Service Method Contract> has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy293.getTaxonomyBasicInformation(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        <Business methods calls>
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
        at com.db.fdw.common.gxt.web.server.DefaultRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(DefaultRemoteServiceServlet.java:71)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.db.fdw.dbent.api.FdwAuthFilter.doFilter(FdwAuthFilter.java:35)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https:<Service URL> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.c
ertpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1346)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        ... 56 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to
requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:568)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:539)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:248)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:636)
        at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1444)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:266)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1550)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1579)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1520)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1317)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
        ... 83 more
```

Please provide any ideas/help, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the certificate in JDK security. Follow below 2 step and get done.

- Step-1 Goto Below java security directory

> /path/to/java/jdk/jre/lib/security

- Step-2 Run below command

> keytool -import -keystore cacerts -file /path/to/your/cert.cer